# vsftpd on CentOS - permissions

Tags: permissions, centos, apache-http-server, ftp, webserver

I've searched a lot and I can't find a properly answer for my case. I think it has something to do with groups, but I can't discover a solution that fits me.

So here's the deal:

I have a home server on CentOS, and I use vsftpd.

I created a user `miguel` and made the default ftp location to `var/www/html/` (as I'm the only user).

The question is - I have a php script which allows everyone on the internet to upload files to my server (in this moment, they're going to a folder called `user_files`, inside `var/www/html`). When I check locally the permissions of that folder, they are assigned to `apache:apache`. When I access via ftp with the user `miguel` I can't access/write on that folder.

How can I override all permissions, to give `miguel``, locally or via ftp, a "superaccess" permission to that folder?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could add `miguel` the the `apache` group and make sure the group has write access to the folder.

```
useradd -G apache miguel
chmod 764 -R /var/www/html
```

You might want to adapt `chmod` to fit your requirements.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. But no, it didn't worked. `miguel` is already in the group `apache` and still doesn't have write permissions on that folder.

Comment: Are you sure your vsftpd does not `jail` your user so that you can never change directory to `/var/www/html`? This link might help you if you are unsure of what `jailed` is http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=518293